# Fetch the maximum value of yesterday and today odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In database there are many dates but i want to **fetch the maximum value of yesterday and today** of particular city.
Below code i tried but i gives same value for each city:

What i want is if there are multiple cities and they have their values then how to get maximum value for each particular city.

Suppose, first two values are created yesterday and rest are created today.

Let,A,B,C,D are cities and A have values 45,62,98,62,37 & B have values 85,26,33,44,55 & C have values 74,56,20,35,96 & D have values 45,52,69,85,77 and their creation date are different some A values are created yesterday and some A values are created today.Similarly, for B,C,D.

Now, from above data i want:
**Max values** of A,B,C,D **created yesterday**.(i.e.  A=62, B=85,C=74,D=52) &

**Max values** of A,B,C,D **created today**.(i.e.  A=98, B=55,C=96,D=85).
Below is the code which i tried:

```
check = self.env['model_name'].search([])
for i in check:
    self.env.cr.execute("""where write_date<current_date 
         and write_date >=current_date - interval '1 day';
         """,)
    ab=self.env.cr.fetchone()
    print(ab,"::::::::::::::")
```